# Break while loop and get the count

Tags: php, mysql

I'm unable to break the while loop.

```
<?php $quizsections = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quiz_sections");
while($quizsectionsrslt = mysql_fetch_array($quizsections)){
    $quizsectionsid        = $quizsectionsrslt['id'];
    $quizsectionsheading   = $quizsectionsrslt['heading'];
    $quizsectionsquizid    = $quizsectionsrslt['quizid'];
    $quizsectionsfirstslot = $quizsectionsrslt['firstslot'];
    echo $quizsectionsheading."<br />";

    $quizslots = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quiz_slots WHERE `quizid`=$quizsectionsquizid");
    while($quizslotsrslt = mysql_fetch_array($quizslots)){
        $quizslotids = $quizslotsrslt['questionid'];
        $questions = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM question WHERE `id`=$quizslotids");

        while($questionsrslt = mysql_fetch_array($questions)){
            echo $questiontext = $questionsrslt['id']."<br />";
        }
    }
}?>
```

**It is displaying the output like**

`Aptitude`

> 1 2 3 .... 40

`Arithmetic`

> 1 2 3 ... 40

`Reasoning`

> 1 2 3 ... 40

`Computers`

> 1 2 3 ... 40

**But the output i want**

`Aptitude`

> 1 2 3 ... 10

`Arithmetic`

> 11 12 13 ... 25

`Reasoning`

> 26 27 28 ... 30

`Computers`

> 31 32 33 ... 40

Tables structure

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I asked this question for 3 times from last 4 days. Nobody can get the right idea. And i didn't get the right support from here

i already provided my code and the output too. And what the output requirement i have. :( :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use LIMIT on the MySQL query to change the output based on the first slot

```
<?php $quizsections = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quiz_sections");
while($quizsectionsrslt = mysql_fetch_array($quizsections)){
    $quizsectionsid        = $quizsectionsrslt['id'];
    $quizsectionsheading   = $quizsectionsrslt['heading'];
    $quizsectionsquizid    = $quizsectionsrslt['quizid'];
    $quizsectionsfirstslot = $quizsectionsrslt['firstslot'];
    echo $quizsectionsheading."<br />";

    $quizslots = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quiz_slots WHERE `quizid`=$quizsectionsquizid LIMIT ".($quizsectionsfirstslot-1).", 10");
    while($quizslotsrslt = mysql_fetch_array($quizslots)){
        $quizslotids = $quizslotsrslt['questionid'];
        $questions = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM question WHERE `id`=$quizslotids");

        while($questionsrslt = mysql_fetch_array($questions)){
            echo $questiontext = $questionsrslt['id']."<br />";
        }
    }
}?>
```

Comment: Danny, Awesome helping. Got the output whatever i want. I really loose hopes on that from here. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: And now i will try to get the count of each section. :)

Comment: i got the count too. I'm having one small doubt on it. may i ask you?

Comment: Yeah sure, also you have the other answer as marked as the correct answer, even though your comments on it indicates that its wrong

Comment: Ok. If, i have 15 questions in Reasoning topic only, then it won't be display Reasoning 15 and remaining topics having 10. Right?

Comment: If you do another column on your DB, and set how many records you want in each topic, then you can modify the LIMIT statement similar to the starting point, just replace the 10 with your field that shows how many per topic

Comment: I'm uploading a questions file in my website, then those questions stored in `questions` table. And, the `id`s are storing in `quiz_slots` table too. You may look into image which is i added in above.

Comment: Yeah I can see your doing that, if you add the additional column into the quiz_sections that will answer the first bit you mentioned

Comment: :)  I'm not doing this from my end. It was developed my Moodle. I'm working on that database only.

Comment: Finally got the result.I would like to contact you for few moments whenever it's hard to me to do the task. If you feel free, please provide me any of your id or mail id.  :)

Comment: It's great help to me.

Comment: No problem Raja, i'm on facebook, linked in, and so on

Answer (score 0):

You can stop executing a loop by adding:

```
break;
```

On the line that you want to stop

Comment: Stick `$count = 0` before the loop and `$count++;` in it. Then you can get the number of times you went through the loop before breaking.

Comment: DanielM, i mean not like that,
Please give a look into the output what i got, And what i required in the above mentioned question. :)

Comment: Hope, i may get the correct output, if anybody helps me.

Comment: I asked this question for 3 times from last 4 days. Nobody can get the right idea. And i didn't get the right support from here.

Comment: i already provided my code and the output too. And what the output requirement i have. :( :(